# Available message types in JMS?

Tags: java, jms, messaging, enterprise

This is based on a past exam question.

The question is asking to describe the **four** types of message available using **JMS**.

The problem is it says the four, not just four. So it assumes their is only four, no more no less.

However according to [this site](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/Message.html) their seems to be **five**;

1. streams
2. maps
3. text
4. objects
5. bytes

*Another book states that XML is another potential type in future versions of JMS. Is XML already available?

Am I missing something or is the question just wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** There are 5 types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sun's [JMS Spec 1.1](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/docs.html) in Section 3.1.1 lists the same five message types.  The question appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to pass XML, you use bytes.

Comment: TextMessage can be used for XML, since XML is text.